# Identify smd capacitor value and name

Tags: capacitor, surface-mount

Can anyone help me to identify the SMD capacitor in this photo? (at least I think it's a capacitor!)

[image]

Comment: Unsolder and measure it.

Comment: Since there are no values present, the only real way to know the value would be to desolder it. If it is a capacitor, it is most likely a tantalum capacitor. It looks like it could also be an unusually, shaped diode.

Comment: Maybe a photo with more of the board?  There might be a marking that could indicate whether it is a capacitor or a diode (or something else.)

Comment: A closup photo like that is useful, but a wider shot showing context would be useful too.

Answer (score 4):

It's SMD diode - probably 1N4148/CD4148 (or similar small signal diode) in 0805 package (by the looks of it).

Datasheet: http://www.taiwansemi.com/products/datasheet/TS4148%20RYG_L14.pdf

Answer (score 3):

That device doesn't have any markings to tell its value.

The one-sided stripe might indicate it's a polarized device – maybe a diode?

Answer (score 3):

Being black with a stripe near one end hints that this is not a capacitor at all.  Such stripes usually show polarity.  While some capacitors do have polarity, this doesn't look like the right kind of package for that.

It might be a diode, but since it has no other marking, you can't be sure other than by measuring it.  Seeing some context around this part may also help.